# React trying to access file at a wrong path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I've created a React app using create-react-app and I can't eject it to change the webpack configs.

That being said, I'm trying to use index.scss as a hub and I'm importing all .scss files from sections folder.
At _header.css, I have the following line working fine:

```
background-image: url(../img/bg_desktop.jpg);
```

But when I import it to the index.scss file:

```
@import './sections/header.scss';
```

React throws the following error:

*Module not found: You attempted to import ../img/bg_desktop.jpg which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.*

When I change the path to "./img/bg_desktop.jpg" it doesn't find it either.. so it's working with neither relative path.
Is there a way to fix this without ejecting the whole thing?

This is how it's structured:

[image]

Comment: how about just `img/bg_desktop.jpg` ?

Comment: It worked. I can't believe it hahahaha Make your comment into an answer and I'll accept it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `img/bg_desktop.jpg` as `./` represents the current directory, which I believe can be changed during run time.

Comment: Yeap, that's it. My line of thought was that SASS would understand `./` as a relative path to the importer file - clearly not the case. Thanks a lot, man!